# Native linking failed. Please review the build log in Xamarin Cross platform

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We are getting following errors in VS 2017 at build Xamarin cross platform app existing project.

```
Native linking failed. Please review the build log.         
Native linking error: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386          
Native linking error: warning: ignoring file /Users/user1/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ItsLiveNow.iOS/009be1dc70d68b6f7ff589eefa4397ac/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/LFLiveKit.framework/LFLiveKit, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/user1/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ItsLiveNow.iOS/009be1dc70d68b6f7ff589eefa4397ac/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/LFLiveKit.framework/LFLiveKit (2 slices)           
Duplicate symbol in: /Users/user1/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ItsLiveNow.iOS/009be1dc70d68b6f7ff589eefa4397ac/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/i386/main.o (Location related to previous error)            
Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_main'.           
Duplicate symbol in: /Users/user1/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ItsLiveNow.iOS/009be1dc70d68b6f7ff589eefa4397ac/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/leveldb-library(leveldb_main.o) (Location related to previous error)            
The "ProcessGoogleServicesJson" task was not given a value for the required parameter "ResStringsPath".
```

Can you please help me to get proper solution and any regarding help links ?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I suggest that you should provide more information . And here is a similar issue that you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468557/how-to-implement-push-notification-for-xamarin-android/50480591.

Comment: I resolved this error by reinstall #mono.android and #Xamarin.ios dll in assemblies dependency reference.
I m getting following error in ios project after rebuild project.

Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Internals.ResourceLoader/ResourceLoadingQuery::.ctor()', referenced from the method 'System.Void MyLiveApp.App::InitializeComponent()' in 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Can you please give me a solution regarding this issue?

Comment: Can you provide your sample?

Comment: I have set this configuration in my app project.
`Configuration : Visual Studio 2017, Xamarin.Forms(4.0.0.250467-pre7) , Xamarin.ios(v4.0.30319),Mac OS:10.14.1,Xcode:10.1`

Comment: I suggest that you can provide your sample so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I can't give you any a sample from my side, please help me if you can another way solve this error.

Comment: The information you provide is not enough

Comment: Ok. thanks. I will updating more information.

Comment: Happy coding :)